# no borders around an empty cell while generating HTML using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, sql-server-2008, xslt, xhtml

I am transforming `XSLT` to generate the `HTML` with `XML` generated from SQL Server database.
I am populating a `HTML` table. But the problem is if the cell is empty border does not appear around that cell.

I have tried using

```
ISNULL(FirstName, '&nbsp;') AS 'FirstName'
```

but it giving me the output as bellow:

```
<SpokenTo>&amp;nbsp;</SpokenTo>
```

Is there any other way to insert `&nbsp;` in empty cell to get the border around it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

`ISNULL(FirstName, ' ') AS 'FirstName'`

with a space in between the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're not entering a non-breaking space, you're entering the text '&nbsp;'.

You could try entering a hard space directly (instead of hitting the space bar, hold left alt and type '0160' on the keypad), but to be honest I'm not convinced that's the best solution, it might cause problems with some character encodings.

Failing that, it's worth investigating how to add html entities; you'll have the same problem trying to add a <, >, or &, you might be able to find some examples that add those.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I don't think we can write anything while holding Alt key. I tried it in SQL Server management studio.

Answer (score 0):

It looks more like a problem with disable-output-escaping not turned on.

Try using <mycell disable-output-escaping="yes">&#160;</mycell>

Also if you are using PHP it has option which is called preserveWhitespace, you might wanna make sure it is set to its default value TRUE.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.preservewhitespace

Comment: Not sure about it then, but Google brought up this page which also includes a few passages about .NET:
http://www.xmlplease.com/whitespace